# Logical Parentheses for regex...?

Tags: regex

So I am new to regex.... and what I can't make sense of is this...

How can I search for a specific regex each time in a string, ie match all occurences of 'test' in a given string.... What could I use as a logical parantheses?

```
/(test)*/
```

This returns several matches/Backreferences and doesn't seem to be meant for logically grouping/order of execution.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.  Can you give an example where this would be useful?

Comment: Its not very clear what kind of result you want. Can you post a sample input string and desired output?

Comment: Are you trying to grab all instances of the word 'test' in string so you can replace them with something else? Can you elaborate on your goal a bit more?

Comment: I'm just trying to match the word test in any given string. BUT, my example didn't quite make sense because of my limited understanding of regex, so I will update with a different example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop parenthesis from creating match groups, start them with `?:`

```
/(?:test)*/
```

This just matches "test" several times in a row, without saving the matched substrings anywhere.

Comment: Let me ask this, is there a need for (?: <regex> ) often, in the effect of a logical parentheses?

Comment: It is worth noting that this construct is specific to Perl (and PCRE-related systems, which most languages can be).  Doesn't work in grep, awk, and other POSIX-style regular expression environments.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex specifies only contiguous occurences of test.  For all, you usually need to us a flag to indicate that you wnt to match every occurence, not just the first.  In most languages, this is indicated by using the 'g' flag.

```
/test/g
```